# Redirect 404 pages to homepage Zend2

Tags: url-rewriting, zend-framework2

In zend 2 when there is no url matching in the controller action it sends it to 404 page.

Now i want all 404 to redirect to home page. Below is the code in module.config.php file.

Dont know where to put any action which will be called automatically when any 404 url is called.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'application/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index'     => __DIR__ .     '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple event listener, listening with a high priority, should suffice.

Not in any way tested, however it should give you an idea of how to intercept the error.

```
// Module.php
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function($e) {
        $error = $e->getError();
        switch ($error) {
            case Application::ERROR_CONTROLLER_NOT_FOUND:
            case Application::ERROR_CONTROLLER_INVALID:
            case Application::ERROR_ROUTER_NO_MATCH:

                $response = $event->getResponse();
                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', '/home');
                $response->setStatusCode(302);

                return $response;
            break;
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

I also would recommend taking a good look at the code in `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\RouteNotFoundStrategy` as this is the 'default' listener for rendering the `404` template. The above is doing the same thing *earlier* and rather than rendering a view model it just returns the response (with a redirect).

Comment: cant we do this in a simple way. Instead of adding class etc for this

Comment: @RahulTailwal Sorry, I don't understand; there is no new classes in my example. The above code would be within the `onBoostrap` method of an *existing* `Module.php`.

Comment: i dont have module.php file. Is it the same module.config.php file but it has only an array of configuration of routing

Comment: i want to do something with this file. https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php

Comment: No they are different, you **will** have a `Module.php` class. It's even [in the skeleton application you linked too](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/Module.php).